413 request entity too large - when i upload something using mobile device (on systems its working)
enter image description here413 Request entity too large - only when I upload using mobile device
when we use system/mac, it's working without any issues till 1gb of files.
same node express server. (same application on different devices)
but for mobile even with 30mb, I am having the issue.
existing limits:
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '1500mb', parameterLimit: 1000000 }))
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '1500mb', parameterLimit: 1000000 }))
